# How to convert a stereoscopic image to separate layers?

Tags: images, 3d-graphics

I am wondering, is it possible to convert a stereoscopic (3D, i.e. captured with two side-by-side cameras) to separate layers?

The images are in .MPO or .JPS format – essentialy two images next to each other.

I would like to animate a moving from left to right parallax effect on a non-3D display. I am mainly asking this because I would like to convert photos captured on the 3ds or images made in Colors!3d to layers on the computer

Comment: How is the image encoded? Anaglyph? How does it look like? Can you please give us an example?

Comment: .mpo or .jps format. Essentially two images next to each other. I am mainly asking this because I would like to convert photos captured on the 3ds or images made in Colors!3d to layers on the computer. An example: